# How to get session information for Azure SQL Database errors via Kusto?

Tags: azure-sql-database, errors

I have a kusto query that finds errors in some of my Azure SQL Databases:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where Category == "Errors"
and DatabaseName_s has "<redacted>"
| project TimeGenerated, error_number_d, Message, LogicalServerName_s, DatabaseName_s, query_hash_s, client_ip_s, application_name_s, session_server_principal_name_s
| sort by TimeGenerated desc
```

However, the last 3 columns (client_ip_s, application_name_s, session_server_principal_name_s) do not appear in the output. How can I get that information included?

Comment: The only things in scope at all after `summarize count(), min(TimeGenerated), max(TimeGenerated)` should be `count_, min_TimeGenerated, max_TimeGenerated` so I'm not sure how you are seeing anything. Did you miss out a `by` in your summarize?

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for pointing out my copy/paste error. I have corrected the query text.